# image uploading errors

Tags: php, image-upload

So I have this issue with my errors not showing up when I test to see if they are showing up when they are supposed to. When I select an file, my script is only supposed to accept image files as well as nothing bigger than 2MB. I haven't written the part that actually uploads the images to the database and the albums that I created but regardless, I should get some sort of error instead of just passing anything through..I need help! Thanks in advance!

Here is the file that processes the image and will eventually upload:

```
<?php
include 'init.php';

if(!logged_in()){
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include 'template/header.php';
?>

<h3>Upload Image</h3>

<?php

if(isset($FILES['image'], $_POST['album_id'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
$image_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $image_name)));

$album_id = $_POST['album_id'];

$errors = array();

if (empty($image_name) || empty($album_id)){
    $errors[] = 'Something is missing';
} else {

    if(in_array($image_ext, $allowed_ext) === false){
        $errors[] = 'File type not allowed';
    }

    if($image_size > 2097152){
        $errors[] = 'Maximum file size is 2MB'; 
    }

    if(album_check($album_id) === false){
        $errors[] = 'Couldn\'t upload to that album';
    }

}

if(!empty($errors)){
    foreach ($errors as $error){
        echo $error, '<br />';
    }
} else {
    // upload image
}
}

$albums = get_albums();

if(empty($albums)){
echo '<p>You don\'t have any albums. <a href="create_album.php">Create an album</a></p>';
} else {
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Choose a file:<br /><input type="file" name="image" /></p>
<p>
Choose an album:<br />
<select name="album_id">
    <?php 
    foreach ($albums as $album){
        echo '<option value="', $album['id'], '">', $album['name'], '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>

<?php
}

include 'template/footer.php';
?>
```

I think my issue is around my errors but I'm not sure, again any help is appreciated! Thanks!
-TechGuy24

Comment: have you set enctype property of form tag to enctype="multipart/form-data"??

Comment: @SandeepTawaniya you can see it clearly in his example

Comment: ohh.. sorry!! i don't see that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `if(isset($FILES['image'], $_POST['album_id'])){`

To `if(isset($_FILES['image'], $_POST['album_id'])){`

Comment: That fixed it! wow, I can't believe I missed that..Thanks AlienWebguy!

Comment: wow, I had to stare at the answer for five minutes before I realized there was an underscore missing! time to go to bed...